# Library function that implements TPM2_MakeCredential

Tags: tpm

For remote attestation using a TPM, on the server-side I need the TPM2_MakeCredential function. Note that this function is implemented in the TPM but it is a bit off because it doesn't depend on any TPM state, it's completely stateless (unlike the TPM2_ActivateCredential function - to be run on the client-side - which critically depends on TPM keys). According to the documentation, it's provided as a convenience. That's OK but the problem is the server doesn't have (nor requires) a TPM. But I still want to use the TPM2_MakeCredential function.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a library implementation of this function. There's a full-blown TPM2.0 emulator provided by Microsoft that the TPM.MSR libraries can interface to. This works, but it requires starting and managing the simulator process which sets up sockets etc. which I would rather avoid. I am wondering if there's a pure C/C++/C# implementation provided as a library? I have been working with various solutions but the function is not trivial to re-implement, and it's also not trivial to extract from the simulator.

Comment: Not that I know of. FWIW the simulator has a very small footprint. You can configure it to run on startup and it will be one of many deamons running on that server. If this really bothers you extracting MakeCredential is not trivial but it shouldn't be a big deal either...

Comment: I think subprocesses etc. are always a mess if they can be avoided. Depends on the solution context of course. Extracting MakeCredential() does pull a lot of code with it (to the point you are essentially just creating an in-process hosted version of the simulator code with some parts stripped away ;-)) so it might be easier to write from scratch. However, as noted in my answer below I found the TPM.MSR library implements the functionality.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that it was implemented in TPM.MSR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the TPM.MSR library itself exposes this functionality (implemented purely in the library itself, not relying on a TPM) via the CreateActivationCredentials() function on TpmPublic.